# Rotating a view around a fixed point - ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to rotate a UIView around a fixed point.

```
bubbleTail = [[BubbleTail alloc] initWithFrame:bubbleTailFrame];
[self addSubview:bubbleTail];
bubbleTail.layer.anchorPoint = triangle_top_left;
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 180 / 180.0);
bubbleTail.transform = transform;
```

This works only if I comment the .anchorPoint line.
How do I rotate the view about a point inside the view?

Comment: What happens if you don't comment it out? Nasal demons?

Comment: Have a read here http://ronnqvi.st/translate-rotate-translate/

Comment: This link has a few examples similar to what I want. To make myself clear, one point on the border of the view has to be in the same position in the superview, even after the view rotates, i.e like the hand on a clock.

Comment: What is `triangle_top_left` in your code? Is it normalized (between 0 and 1)?

Comment: No it is an ordinary CGPoint. To be clear, I need to fix a point in the view to remain in the same position. So when I  rotate the view, this point should be the axle of rotation.

Comment: @CharlesD'Monte the anchor point is in the unit coordinate space (normalized). Try dividing x by the width and y with the height to get two values between 0 and 1 and use that as the anchor point.

Comment: [my article here](http://blog.ideveloper.tv/understanding-the-anchor-point/) may also help you understand how the anchor points works.

Answer (score 2):

The below should help. The tricky part is that setting the anchorpoint after adding a view with a frame then moves the view. I've gotten around this by initiating the UIView without a frame, then setting the position, bounds and anchorpoint of its layer. I then use the rotation to rotate around the anchor point.

```
CABasicAnimation *rotation;
rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
rotation.duration = 60.0;
rotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

UIView *myview = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:myview];
[myview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]; 
[myview.layer setPosition:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
[myview.layer setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[myview.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[myview.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"myAnimation"];
```

Someone please correct me if this is not the best method or if there are mistakes - I only know what I currently know - e.g. when I should use a . or f after a float.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` rotates it around the `center` of the view?

Say you have point `P (px,py)` in view, you want view to be rotated around that.
Let's `A(ax,ay)` = `P` - `center` = (px - centerx, py - centery).
And you have angle `alpha`.

Then you could make a translate matrix with `- A`, then multipy it with rotation matrix with `alpha`, then multipy it with translate matrix with `+ A`.

The functions you'll need are: [CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation), [CGAffineTransformMakeRotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation), [CGAffineTransformConcat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformConcat).

P.S. Not sure if this will work (also not sure how view rect is represented, maybe it first assumption about rotation around center is wrong, then you shoud assume A = P), but that's how it's done with affine transforms.

Comment: My problem is that when I rotate the view, it should rotate like a hand of the clock where the center is my point. How do I get this?

Comment: Rotation with affine matrix from CGAffineTransformMakeRotation is produced around the center of coordinates (0,0). So at first you'll need to get where is that center (just rotate the view or google, it will be in the center of the view or at the top left corner), I'm not sure where. Then choose a point (looks like in the middle of the right edge of the view) to rotate your view around. Then act as I wrote in the answer, center = (wi/2, he/2)[center of view] or (0,0)[top left corner], P should be in view's coordinates with (0,0) at the top left corner. Not sure if it sounds understandable=)

Comment: Not sure what do you mean with "fix", but you could use any point with this. My answer is just from basic knowledge of linear algebra, it's up to you to implement it to solve your problem.

Comment: I need to fix a point, which is inside the view. So, when I rotate the view, this point should be the axle of rotation.